# Group with given characteristic subgroup

Tags: group-theory

If $N$ and $H$ are finite groups, then there exist group $G$ s.t $N$ is normal in $G$ and $G/N\cong H$ (ex. $N\times H, N\rtimes H$ etc.)

Does there exist a group $G$ s.t. $N$ is *characteristic subgroup* of $G$ and $G/N\cong H$?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misread the question.

Comment: @Geoff: It seemed to work to me, what was wrong?

Comment: The PO seems to want to fix both $H$ and $N.$ I thought $N$ was allowed to be chosen.

Comment: My gut feeling is that the answer is "no"; here's where I would look for a counterexample: there are $2$-groups $M$ and $K$ such that the "base" subgroup of the wreath product $M\wr K$ is not characteristic, and I would try $N=M$ and $H=K$. But I don't remember off-hand the structures of the groups $M$ and $K$, so I can't check.

Answer (score 5):

Try taking $N = H = $ non-abelian finite simple group.  It seems rather unlikely that $G$ could be anything other than $N \times N$, and in that case $N$ is not characteristic since there is an automorphism that exchanges the two copies of $N$.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a lot of 'proving' going on here.

Comment: As he said, "try taking...". So, take your simplest, easiest group to work with. Say, $C_2$...Done.

Comment: @Swlabr: $C_2$ doesn't work because $G$ could be $C_4$ which has a characteristic copy of $C_2$.  Abelian groups can combine as composition factors in many different ways; that's why I suggested trying a *non-abelian* simple group.

Comment: @jspecter: I know I haven't proven my answer.  I couldn't figure out how to prove it so I just offered it as a plausible suggestion.

Comment: @Ted: Eeverything you say in your answer is accurate, or, at least, can be made so. As Jack Schmidt does in a particular case, the key point to note is that if $N$ is a finite simple (non-Abelian) group, then $N$ does not embed in its outer automorphism group ${\rm Out}(N).$ However, for the moment I do not see an elementary proof of this fact, apart from the fact that the outer automorphism group of a finite simple group is solvable, which requires the classification of finite simple groups (but there may be one- just I don't see it yet).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I had forgotten what the question asked!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a proof for a nice case of Ted's answer:

Suppose *G* is a group with normal subgroup *N* such that both *G*/*N* and *N* are simple groups of order 60.  Let *C* be the centralizer of *N* in *G*.  Then *G*/*C* embeds in Aut(*N*), a group of order 120.  *CN* = *C*×*N* since *C*∩*N*=1 and *C* and *N* centralize each other.  In particular, *C* ≅ *CN*/*N* ≤ *G*/*N* embeds as a normal subgroup into the simple group of order 60, so has order 60 or 1.  Hence *G*/*C* has order 60 or order at least 60⋅60 > 120 = |Aut(*N*)|, a contradiction.  Hence *C* is a simple group of order 60, and *G* = *CN* = *C*×*N* is a direct product of isomorphic simple groups and so *N* is not characteristic in *G*.

I believe the same holds for any non-abelian simple group *N* ≅ *G*/*N*, but I've forgotten how to prove *G* = *CN* in general without using a little machinery. If *G* is not a direct product of non-abelian simple groups, then Fit<sup>*</sup>(*G*) = *N*, and so Bender's theorem shows *C* = 1, a contradiction.

Comment: Is there some way to see the contradiction from $C=1$ besides knowing the order of $\mbox{Aut}(N)$ and then comparing it with the order of $G$?

Comment: @Ted: If *C* = 1, then *G* ≤ Aut(*N*), so we need to know something about the automorphism groups of simple groups.  I like to phrase it as $G/CN$ ≤ Out(*N*), where the left hand side is a quotient of a simple group and the right hand side is solvable, so the left hand side is trivial.  How do we know Out(*N*) does not contain a subgroup isomorphic to *N*? Well, in all known simple groups this is easy, but in general it is called Schreier's conjecture and so far requires the CFSG to prove.  Notice that Out(2×2×2×2) contains 2×2×2×2, so it is not completely clear why *N* is not in Out(*N*).

Comment: (Oh, this is the same as Geoff's earlier comment on Ted's answer.)